# Color gradient for background

Tags: android

How to  give background color gradient as shown in the image
[image: Image with gradient]

How to write the code so as to show the image as appearing in the attachment

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post some examples of what you have tried, so we can help you diagnose what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="Your Color"
    android:endColor="Your Color"
    android:startColor="Your Color"
    android:type="linear" />



</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

create **gradient.xml** in **/res/drawable**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

and in your **main.xml** layout file in **/res/layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient">

</LinearLayout>
```

you can specify the angle by replacing the **android:angle** value and start/end colour by replacing **android:startColor** and **android:endColor**

Answer (score 0):

Make a xml file in res>drawable folder named background.xml and edit it as below :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="radial"
android:centerX="50%" 
android:centerY="50%" 
android:startColor="#FFFF8205" 
android:endColor="#FFF7F7F7" 
android:gradientRadius="100"/>
</shape>
```

Now in your activity_main.xml file reference this as background of the parent layout

```
<LinearLayout
.......
android:background="@drawable/background">
.....
</LinearLayout>
```